# Is there a single word that means a person whose sole reason for existence is to annoy and aggravate others"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was told by someone that it was

> **nimnal, nimnle,** or **nimnel**

but I can't find it nor do I know how to spell it.

I hope that someone knows and that there actually *is* a word for this type of person.

Comment: Curious about the downvote. What's the problem with this question *anonymous?*

Comment: @M.Mat I call it *driveby downvoting*, and it's part of our "welcome" to low-rep users to let them know how unworthy they are to post here. I find it even more noxious on answers. But, here, let me do my part.

Comment: @deadrat ironically would your "driveby downvote"  behavior not be the perfect example of the OP's question? JUST SAYIN - i would call that person an asshole.

Comment: @Alaskaman Well, I find it annoying, but I'm in the minority on this issue, and I don't think we can conclude that a driveby downvoter's sole reason for existence is to annoy. We may assume that such a downvote on questions signals the unworthiness of the question and the moral and intellectual failure of the questioner. I find such downvotes on answers much worse: if the answer is correct, then the questioner may be lead to doubt the answer's accuracy; if the answer is incorrect or incomplete, the answerer doesn't know what to fix.

Comment: @deadrat Hear Hear ( said in my best British accent ).  I agree completely about some of the pompousness that the  Judgmental and Draconian stack reputation system seems to facilitate.  I just thought the irony was sweet.   There also seems to be little allowance for humor. ( Allowance? is that the right word to use here .) See what i did there? a question on English usage in a comment on the English Language and usage stack. Gosh i do not want be labeled a nimnal, nimnle, or nimnel

Comment: This sounds like a variant on "nimrod" in its sense of an "idiot". Urban Dictionary has many similar sounding derogative words beginning "nim-". Nimnal, nimnad, nimnit, nimno, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound at all like *nimnal* or the other variants the OP mentions, but 
***gadfly*** fits the definition.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_gadfly)

> A gadfly is a person who interferes with the status quo of a society or
>   community by posing novel, potently upsetting questions, usually
>   directed at authorities. The term is originally associated with the
>   ancient Greek philosopher Socrates, in his defense when on trial for
>   his life.
>
> The term "gadfly" (Ancient Greek: μύωψ, mýops[1]) was used by Plato in
>   the Apology[2] to describe Socrates's relationship of uncomfortable
>   goad to the Athenian political scene, which he compared to a slow and
>   dimwitted horse.
>
> During his defense when on trial for his life, Socrates, according to
>   Plato's writings, pointed out that dissent, like the gadfly, was easy
>   to swat, but the cost to society of silencing individuals who were
>   irritating could be very high: "If you kill a man like me, you will
>   injure yourselves more than you will injure me" because his role was
>   that of a gadfly, "to sting people and whip them into a fury, all in
>   the service of truth." This may have been one of the earliest
>   descriptions of gadfly ethics.

As should be clear from the context, a gadfly is a fly that irritates domestic animals.  See [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gadfly).

Comment: I've really only heard gadfly in the context of a bothersome, drunken gossipy type whose presence is irritating to others. Most often used in a dismissive fashion about an "unimportant person." I've always felt it was a classist comment.

Comment: I've generally taken "gadfly" to be somewhat literal -- like a fly buzzing around, annoying you.  I usually see it used to imply an "oddball" or "outsider" who asks annoying/embarrassing questions, as when a politician is doing what he expects to be a friendly "meet and greet" with some bigwigs and this guy shows up and starts asking questions about their "smelly" financial arrangements.

Answer (score 2):

From Yiddish, [*nudnik*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nudnik?s=t)

*noun*  a difficult person or situation

Synonyms for nudnik: headache, nuisance, pain in the butt

Word Origin & History
nudnik 1947, from Yiddish, with agential suffix -nik (q.v.) + Pol. nuda "boredom" or Rus. nudnyi "tedious, boring," from O.C.S. *nauda-, from PIE *neuti- "need" from root *nau- "death, to be exhausted"

The American idiom is "pain in the butt" which encompasses a whole host of offensive behaviors.

Comment: Attribution and quoting the text directly instead of posting screenshots: please do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Urban Dictonary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nimnul) has an entry for a similar-sounding word whose definition seems on point:

> **nimnul**
>
> A derrogatory term coined by Mork from Ork, similar to 'schmuck' or 'nerd'
>
> "I feel like a Nimnul"
>
> by brad May 28, 2003

Other contributors to that reference work provide similar entries for the spellings [*nimnu*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nimnu) ("a person being stupid and or careless"), [*nimno*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nimno) ("An idiot, fool or spaz. Also, a person who is not tech savvy.") and [*nimnoo*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nimnoo) ("A dolt. A goober. A macaroon. An affectionate term for 'idiot'. Another term for 'nimrod'.")

Urban Dictionary's attribution of *nimnul* to Mork (Robin Williams) of the TV show [*Mork & Mindy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077053/) (which ran on U.S. television from 1978 to 1982) seems accurate. Mork (of planet Ork) was most famous for his greeting "Nanu, nanu!" But he also seems to have introduced *nimnul* to a planet of couch potatoes. A March 13, 2001 [posting by geeklizard](https://everything2.com/user/geeklizzard/writeups/nimnul) on Everything2.com runs as follows:

> The word "nimnul" made its way into English slang through the late 70's sitcom Mork and Mindy. The goofy alien, Mork from Ork, would call you a nimnul if you were being an idiot.
>
> It is commonly spelled "nimno". A nimno is not just an idiot, but a clueless buffoon who makes an ass of himself without ever knowing it.

The made-up word was sufficiently popular that you could buy an iron-on transfer (for applying to a T-shirt) featuring a picture of Mork and the words "I feel like a... NIMNUL." In fact, those items still sometimes show up for sale [on Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/VINTAGE-MORK-MINDY-T-SHIRT-IRON-ON-ORK-TV-COMEDY-RARE-ROBIN-WILLIAMS-NIMNUL/272712706102?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D41375%26meid%3Dd5299bd7893743c9af85ae9231047b00%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D7%26sd%3D282452924329).